# Is this rust or not, will it spread, how should I repair it?

Tags: paint, rust, body-work

Hit a concrete pole and damaged my Hyundai coupe 2006.

This is side view of car just under door where damaged has occurred.

As you can see paint worked has been pierced and is showing some metal\rust.

1. Is this the rust that spreads or is it just some exposed metal?
2. If it will spread can you tell me what are some quick fixes and also what is a more proper fix?  I don't mind the dents I just want to repair it so it doesn't spread at the moment.
3. If its not the type to spread should I just spray it with black and leave it at that.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this the rust that spreads or is it just some exposed metal?

Hard to say from the picture, but it looks like some rust is beginning. All rust spreads to some extent depending what climate you live in. Especially with exposed metal.

> If it will spread can you tell me what are some quick fixes and also what is a more proper fix?

Quick fix would be to sand it and prime it to prevent further rust. The proper fix would be to have a body shop repair it. They will repair the damage, remove any rust and paint the panel properly.

> If its not the type to spread should I just spray it with black and leave it at that.

Again, depending where you live will determine if it will spread. For instance, if you live in Arizona, you might be able to get away with doing nothing. Alternately, if you live in a wet climate, the rust will move quickly.

In the event you live in a dry climate, it would still be best to sand it down to bare metal, prime it and paint it.

Comment: I added another pic, you can click to enlarge. I dont think this surface developed over time, I think it came instantly as a result of paint pierceing at time of accident, though I could be wrong

Comment: The image is too grainy to see for sure. The area of the car where the damage is at gets a lot of abuse from road debris, so there could be rust under the paint, or the tan color in the image could be filler from a previous repair. Hard to say from just an image.

Answer (score 1):

Picture is not very clear, but looks like rust, and will spread over time, should be able to get some rust inhibitor at your local hardware shop, it should make the rust turn black, this will help slow it down, but as long at its open it will continue to rust over time. A proper sand and clean up with a lick of paint will work the best.

Comment: I added another pic, you can click to enlarge.  I dont think this surface developed over time, I think it came instantly as a result of paint pierceing at time of accident, though I could be wrong.

Comment: could be the result of the accident and a few other factors, including the primer or undercoat color, but it does look like surface rust starting, if you live in a coastal area it wont take long at all for the surface to start going a light orange kind of colour, talking just a few days. but i think it would be wise to have something done, or atleast someone look at it before rust sets in and causes havoc under there